# Animation opens menu incorrectly

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-fragments

I have an issue where my menu in the applications opens in a slightly strange way, I have put a screenshot below to show what I mean. As you can see the menu is  showing and moving the fragment out of the way. I want it so that it appears over the top of the existing fragment. I show this using an animation.

The animation code is as follows:

public static void open(final Context context, final RelativeLayout layout){

```
Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.push_right_out_80);
layout.startAnimation(in);

in.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        layout.startAnimation(anim);
        display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int left = (int) (display.getWidth() * 1.0);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(layout.getLayoutParams());
        params.setMargins(left / 2, 0, -left / 2, 0);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.container);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
});
```

}

This calls an xml file within the anim folder which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="250"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.3"
        android:toXDelta="+50%p"/>
</set>
```

The menu is a listview which is within activity_home.xml and that looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/White">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentspace"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/White">
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The menu goes into the ListView and my fragment goes within the Relative Layout.

To close the menu I have this code (not too sure if this will need to be adapted too?)

```
public static void close(final Context context, final RelativeLayout layout){
    Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.push_left_in);
    layout.startAnimation(out);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

The close code calls another xml file also in the anim folder, that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="250"
        android:fromAlpha="0.3"
        android:fromXDelta="+50%p"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:toXDelta="0"/>
</set>
```

[image: Here you can see the issue in question]

Comment: So you want the "new bookings" listview over the map? Or is it "the green newport" listview that should be in a different spot?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I want the listview over the map please

Comment: I would assume the root of your issue is with a relative layout, as if you move one child element, the rest are going to move. It doesn't look like you are using a DrawerLayout to create a Navigation drawer which might work for your purposes. https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html There is also a blog I found on how to edit the default animation time for it: http://levibostian.com/android-navigation-drawer-animation-duration/